# In Access 2013 ,How to Create a table from 3 worksheets in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access-2013

I have an excel workbook with 3 worksheets of 3 regions (Munich,Frankfurt,Berlin ) with equal number of rows and columns , when i import the workbook into Access, I can  create one separate tables for each specific region , how can i possibly create a single table from multiple worksheets.

I am using Access 2013, and there are no pivot tables functionality that i can possibly use.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `insert into` or a make table query and then use something like this as the data [UNION Query](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) `select * from Munich UNION ALL select * from Franfurt UNION ALL select * from Berlin`  You could do some research on ADO and Excel and do the import from Excel, so it would be a similar input query, but a different connection out side of Access, and you could do the import as `select * from [$Munich] UNION ALL........` etc https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692882.aspx    Essentially the same operation, just omitting the need to import separate sheets first.

Comment: I need to do it in Access

Comment: Yes, you will connect to Excel from access

Comment: I have one more question, i would like to copy multiple rows from one workbook to another , lets say i have data starting in one workbook at A2 row and ends at A108850  and it starts at A2 column and ends at I2 column , how can i copy all that data into another worksheet where row starts with A4 and column starts with A4 and ends with I4 ?

Comment: You'll need to ask another question then :) but as a tip, what you can do in excel, record it as a macro, then inspect that code, and learn from that.  Copy and paste you can record and then learn, probably quicker than typing the question.....